# Animation not playing in Unity 5.3.5f1

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For some reason my animation is not playing, it creature looks like it stuck on a 1st frame.

```
public Animator anim;
void FixedUpdate () {
    targetDistance = Vector3.Distance(target.position, transform.position);


    if (targetDistance < attackDistance)
        {

        attack();
        print("Attack");
    }
}
void attack()
{
    theRigidBody.AddForce(transform.forward * speed);

    anim.Play("attack", -1, 0f);
}
```

It's printing "Attack" in console and creature changes its pose, but for some reason it's not playing.

Answer (score 1):

Did you set your anim variable in the editor ? It probably would lead to an error if not, so you probably did.

Try this :

```
anim.Play("attack", PlayMode.StopAll); 
//or
anim.Play("attack", PlayMode.StopSameLayer);
```

If no success, do this :

```
print(anim.Play("attack", PlayMode.StopAll).ToString());
```

if it returns false, it means that no animation named "attack" was found.

Comment: this is legacy in Unity 5.3